# In a hybrid GE Profile microwave and oven, how can I adjust temp or cook time so top doesn't burn before inside baked? Cookies looked burnt on top

Tags: oven, cookies

When I use my microwave as an oven, which is in the RV,the cookies burn on top before the middle is fully cooked through. I'm thinking because it's height isn't the same as conventional oven...Is there a way I can adjust cooking time or temperature that would even things out for perfect baked goods?

Comment: I think there’s a similar question on here … for now try cooking on the lowest rack, and/or putting an empty sheet pan on the rack above the cookies to prevent radiative heating

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/69267/67  ;  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/105549/67

Comment: You can use aluminum foil to create a 'tent' over the cookies when they start to look too brown but are not done inside. It's not the best for baking;(

Answer (score 2):

You might not be pre-heating enough before baking, go at least 5 or 10 mins. If you unit heats mostly via top-heat, it can emit too much top radiation (browning force) while it gets up to temp. Once hot, the "keep up" pulses of energy are much less concentrated than the "full blast" rate it uses to preheat asap.

You can also try lightly spritzing the cookies with water before baking, so that the top has a bit of extra moisture anchoring it at <100C (too cool to brown), shifting the "soak in" vs "irradiative" ratio to produce a more favorable outcome.

You can also loosely cover your dish w/foil for the first 10 mins or so of baking. This also reduces top heat while the middle rises in temp. The total heat going in remains the same, so your cook time or temp doesn't need adjustment, it just reduces how much of that heat is caught by the top of your food instead of slowly soaking in though the sides/bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your microwave oven uses infrared heat from the top when cooking in this mode. Cooking at a lower heat, or frequently stopping and starting the heating element, may be sufficient (though the latter might damage the oven over time). If possible, cook lower down in the microwave. Alternatively, I’ll bet there’s microwave cookie recipes available, which may work better with your equipment.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I surely wouldn't want to microwave my homemade cookies or cakes, as I'm living in this rv for the time being, but how much would you think I should adjust the temperature, say if it calls for 375...would you put it down to 350?